# IIS Url Rewrite inbound rules process query string

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewriting

I am having trouble in not knowing how to pass the query string to a custom url rewrite module. I have developed a custom url rewrite module that would recieve the complete url ( path + query string) and rewrite some query string values.

How do i pass the query string to custom module when using it in inbound rules ?

**Rule Evaluation Start**

```
RuleName
ReverseProxyInboundRule1 

RequestURL
OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp 

QueryString
sIDType=CUID&iDocID=AbuyCUsQ8L5CskKTqgOSsyw&encoded=9001306c-317f-4332-b03f-44cca57918c2 

PatternSyntax
0 

StopProcessing
true 

RelativePath
/APP.Web/ 

PatternSyntax
Regex
```

**Pattern match**

```
Pattern
BOE/(.*) 

Input
BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp 

Negate
false 

Matched
true
```

Because if you see above/below, my custom module does not receive the query string but only the path `APP.Web/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp`

**Url Changed**

```
OldUrl
/APP.Web/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp?encoded=9001306c-317f-4332-b03f-44cca57918c2 

NewUrl
https://server/BOE/OpenDocument/opendoc/openDocument.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found the answer out myself. You can reference the custom url rewrite module in your inbound or outbound rule Action section. I had to just include the query string also as input to my custom module like below. Where TOKEN is the custom module i had to add to IIS for processing per my requirement.

**Rewritten Url**

```
http://SERVER/BOE/{TOKEN:{R:1}?{QUERY_STRING}}
```